I need to capture and store short bursts of synchronous binary bit-stream, arriving at 1.5meg bits/sec
The binary bit stream arrives on one pin on a circuit board and a synchronous clock arrives on another pin.  I don't need to store the clock - it's just there in case I need to use it during the capture.
The length of each burst can be anywhere from 1200 to 60,000 binary bits - depending on how much data I request each time. I want to capture the simple stream of binary 1's and 0's, then store it, probably broken up into 8-bit bytes and request another burst, so I have time to do the actual storing of the data on a medium, SD card, hard drive etc. because no more data will arrive until I ask for it. As I said, I have the option to request shorter bursts, as short as 1200 bits in a burst, but in all cases the arrival rate of the bit stream is 1.5 meg bits/second.
I've looked at the specs online of several digital storage oscilloscopes but they sample and store csv voltage values, which is useless. I simply want to store the 1's and 0's that arrive during the burst.
Does anyone know of a data capture device that do this? This is a one-shot data capture, where I'm rescuing/recovering data from a device, 5 meg bytes in total and once I have it captured the job is over.
I've looked at a few serial port-to-SD card devices from the Arduino world but they don't seem to fit the requirement. Perhaps there is one that does but I haven't discovered one yet that looks capable of doing this job.
Many thanks to all who take the time to read this and give me pointers.

What levels are used for the signal?  5V/3.3V TTL, RS-232, RS-485, LVDS?  In general you want to look for a logic analyzer or a digital acquisition system rather than an oscilloscope.

For the logical data, a DSO might be a wrong tool compared to a cheap logic analyzer connected to a PC. Or a MCU with a program to capture data in any way and send to PC. Another thing is how to capture the logic levels correctly so you may need some physical interface to convert to logic levels.

The data is pre-cleaned and at TTL levels. a perfect square-wave digital signal, without any jitter. The only issue is that it is fast - 1.5 meg bits/sec. 57600 bits in each burst.   Each one has different content. However I can repeat each burst as often as I need to before moving on.

There is no serial storage IC capable of up to 60,000 bits. You may build a circuit with  a serial to parallel shift register, an address counter and static RAM IC. Some gates as glue logic to control serial and parallel transfer.

Thank you for that excellent suggestion, Uwe. However, I've now found that I can gate the bursts, using another clock pulse that occurs 48 times during the burst, so now I switch on the data stream at any one of those gate pulses.. So now I only get 1200 bits in each burst. My goal s to capture one of those short 1200-bit bursts of binary TTL data and store it as actual 1's and 0's in memory, which I can then download and analyze. Then I'll select a different 1200 bits and so on until I have all 48 pieces stored.
So now if I use a logic analyzer, is there one in particular that you recommend?

This data capture device is called "logic analyzer".
They can be found on eBay starting from $20

I don't want to store a scope picture of the data. What I need stored are the 1's and 0's of the binary bit-stream. Later I can roll through them, find the marker patterns and then I'll be able to reassemble the original data into its original bytes.I'm not sure that those logic analyzers do that. So far what I see is recorded scope pictures of the waveform.
Does anybody know of a device that will do that?

Many thanks, all who responded. - I just ordered a logic analyzer and can write my own decode for it. Great advice - thanks again.
